# Scikit SVM Python : How to pass training set for YES/No decision

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, python-3.4

I want to create SVM Model for smoking decision based on the tweets.

I have set of tweets tagged manually tagged to Yes, No or NA based on whether           the tweet favors smoking or not or the third one if it doesn't say anything.
Using this as train model, i need to make decision for the new tweet whether its Yes/NO/NA.
  I am using Scikit library of Python for this.

I went through the sample examples but i'm not understanding what should be   the input for training model i.e(X, Y values)
I'm not understanding what does it mean by
"take as input two arrays: an array X of size [n_samples, n_features] holding the training samples, and an array y of class labels (strings or integers), size [n_samples]:"
as it says in [Scikit tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html)

Please someone assist what should be the input for this scenario.

Comment: Please refer [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for better response to your question.

Comment: X = number of samples, Y = number of features. Example: you got 1M tweets and these consist of 10M different words. One possible approach is to binary mark the used words in a tweet -> the training-data is now of shape (1M, 10M); 1M samples with 10M features each. Y will be of shape (1M,1) where the values are 0 (YES), 1 (NO), 2 (NA). Keep in mind, that this feature-engineering is just an example. This is the most important step here: how to convert a tweet to some feature-space (same feature-dimension for each tweet!!!).